# Posting to a wall of a facebook user using the graph api

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am new to facebook app development and i am trying to post a simple text on the wall of the user using the https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&message=hello but this does not seem to  be working..Any thoughts as to where i might be going wrong?

Comment: i m using java servlets for app development and do not wish to make use of any third party api's

Comment: did not get any error..its just that nothing would happen..i would  see all the posts on my wall

Comment: is this approach correct for posting?

Comment: are you actually using 'access_token = ACCESS_TOKEN' in the graph api call ?

Comment: Oh no..i am using the app token generated using graph api explorer

Comment: i am familiar with the procedd of OAuth and getting permissions and generating access tokens

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have permissions to post from the app.
2. Add app_id to your call.

Comment: i have the publish_action permission in the extended permissions

Comment: i do not think that  i need to provide app id for this request.as far as i know app id is only  used for getting code and access tokens

Answer (score 0):

If you’re just calling the URL you mentioned, that would be a GET request. To post a message to the user’s wall you have to use method POST. You can test it in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) – change the method to POST via the dropdown, click „add a field” and use name=message and value=your_message …

Comment: ok thanks a lot ..that worked..but how can i make a post request through a servlet?