# How to post the data on facebook wall using access token

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Posting to a wall of a facebook user using the graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908329/posting-to-a-wall-of-a-facebook-user-using-the-graph-api)

How can I post data on facebook wall using access token generated from facebook API.

Answer (score 1):

Using commons-http-client and graph api the code will be something like below.

```
class WallPostService{
    ...
    public makeWallPost(){
        HttpClient client = null;
        PostMethod method = null;
        String urlStr = null;
        String linkText = ""; //Facebook page name or alias
        String linkURL = ""; //Facebook page URL
        String response = null;
        String accessToken = null;

        try{
            urlStr = "https://graph.facebook.com/$PROFILE_ID$/feed";
            urlStr = urlStr.replace("$PROFILE_ID$", facebookId);
            accessToken = getAccessToken();//[USER ACCESS TOKEN]
            client = new HttpClient();
            method = new PostMethod(urlStr);
            method.setRequestHeader("pageEncoding", "UTF-8");
            method.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");

            method.addParameter("access_token", accessToken);
            method.addParameter("message", "");
            method.addParameter("link", "Link of wall post header");
            method.addParameter("name", "Header of wall post");
            method.addParameter("actions", "[{\"name\": \"" + linkText + "\" , \"link\": \"" + linkURL + "\"}]");

            method.addParameter("caption", " ");
            method.addParameter("description", "message body here");
            method.addParameter("picture", "http://www.example.com/test.jpg");
            client.executeMethod(method);
            response = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
           }
           catch(Exception e){

           }
           finally{
               method.releaseConnection();
           }

    }
}
```